# Making fontStyle bold-italic for specific tokens in VS Code on Mac OS

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, styling

I have a windows machine, and I'm able to make some tokens both bold and italic. However, on my mac I can't keep both even if I have the same JSON file on both machines. If i put the `fontStlye: "italic bold", it will only register "italic" and ignore "bold" on my mac, but would register both "italic" and "bold" on my windows machine.
Here is how the JSON file that I have:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": ["punctuation.definition.comment", "comment"],
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#0578fc",
          "fontStyle": "italic bold"
        }
      },

      {
        "scope": [
          //following will be in italic (=FlottFlott)
          "entity.name.type.class", //class names
          "keyword", //import, export, return…
          "storage.modifier", //static keyword
          "storage.type", //class keyword
          "support.class.builtin",
          "keyword.control",
          "constant.language",
          "entity.other.attribute-name",
          "entity.name.method"

          //make those value bold
        ],
        "settings": {
          "fontStyle": "italic bold "
        }
      },
      {
        "scope": [
          //following will be excluded from italics (VSCode has some defaults for italics)
          "invalid",
          "keyword.operator",
          "constant.numeric.css",
          "keyword.other.unit.px.css",
          "constant.numeric.decimal.js",
          "constant.numeric.json"
        ],
        "settings": {
          "fontStyle": ""
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Cobalt2",
  "editor.linkedEditing": true,
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "editor.fontSize": 18,
  "editor.fontFamily": " 'Fira Code iScript', 'Fira Code', 'Courier New', monospace",
  "json.format.enable": true,
```

I tried to change the theme, and looking for any difference in the settings between the two machines but they are in sync, so nothing is changed

Comment: is it a font specific problem? Doe it work if you try any other fonts on your mac? Does it have anything to do with the extra space you have at the end of `""italic bold ""`?

Comment: thank for you answer. Yes it is a problem for this font only, I tried to reinstall the font again, and im still facing the same issue. And, no it is not about the space in "italic bold "

Comment: Very loosely related: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/145018. definitely not an answer.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this when using the Fira Code font on my Windows machine. Italics + bold seems to work just fine there. What is "Fira Code iScript", and where did you install it and you "Fira Code" font from?

Comment: I installed it from the following link: https://github.com/kencrocken/FiraCodeiScript. The reason why I opted for this is because it was the only one that allowed me to customize the font of tokens, whether it was comments or certain words. You can see the tutorial I followed here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PQYdXwJJq-c. I tried to remove "Fira Code iScript" and just opt for "Fira Code" but it didn't give me any of the tokenizing that I had before.